# Como capturar a primeira letra de um nome String e se a letra for 'C' guardar o nome em um vetor?

Tags: java

Tenho um algoritmo que lê um nome de uma pessoa qualquer e se o nome começar com a letra "C" deve capturar o nome  e guardar no vetor. Já tentei de todo jeito mas não consigo fazer.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String nome;
    String []soC = new String[10];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int c = 0; c < soC.length; c++ ){
        System.out.println(" Digite o seu nome:");
        nome = sc.next();
        if(nome){

        }
    }
}
```

Fiz assim:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String nome;
    String []soC = new String[10];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int total = 0;
    for(int c = 0; c < soC.length; c++ ){
        System.out.println(" Digite o seu nome:");
        nome = sc.next();
        if(nome.charAt(0) == 'C'){
            total++;
            soC[total] = nome;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<=total; i++){
        System.out.println(soC[i]);
    }
}
```

**Mas está imprimindo assim:**

```
null
Carla
Carlina
Clau
Craudio
```

Como eu tiro esse null?

Comment: Você retira esse null incrementando a variável total após setar o nome no vetor. Ou você faz isso: "soc[total++] = nome" ou "soc[total] = nome; total++;"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenta usar o método *charAt*, este método retorna o char da String de acordo com o índice especificado, nesse caso o índice 0 que é a primeira letra do nome.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String nome;
    String []soC = new String[10];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int total = 0;
    for(int c = 0; c < soC.length; c++ ){
        System.out.println(" Digite o seu nome:");
        nome = sc.next();
        if(nome.charAt(0) == 'C'){
            soC[total] = nome;
            total++;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<=total; i++){
        if (soC[i] != null){
            System.out.println(soC[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Me ajuda? Editei a pergunta.

Comment: Colocando o incremento "total++" depois da atribuição "soC[total] = nome" vai garantir que a atribuição aconteça começando do primeiro elemento do vetor até o ultimo, lembrando que apenas isso não resolve seu problema. A linha "if (soC[i] != null)" assegura que não seja mostrado o "null".

Comment: Awww deu certo! Mas só não entendi o null no final do vetor. O null no ício do vetor eu entendi, como ele soma um com zero ela guarda na posição 1 do vetor. Mas esse null na última posição que não entendi...mas obrigada.

Comment: Nem sempre o vetor será preenchido completamente, por exemplo, vc informa 9 Strings começando com "C" logo não foi atribuído nenhum valor ao ultimo elemento do vetor. Esse null na ultima posição é apenas o valor default do tipo String. Pesquisa sobre valores padrão ou default.

Answer (score 1):

para retirar o *null* você só precisa trocar o momento em que a variável **total** é incrementada:

```
    for(int c = 0; c < soC.length; c++ ){
    System.out.println(" Digite o seu nome:");
    nome = sc.next();
        if(nome.charAt(0) == 'C')
        {
        soC[total++] = nome;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Eu fiz mas desse jeito não deu certo.